# Ubuntu 14.04 - 32 bit vs 64 bit

Tags: ram

If I install Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit version on a machine with RAM exceeding 4 GB, will it not use more than 4 gb of ram ?

Answer (score 1):

A 32-bit computer has a word size of 32 bits, this limits the memory theoretically to 4GB. This barrier has been extended through the use of 'Physical Address Extension' (or PAE) which increases the limit to 64GB

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit

Comment: I bought a 16 GB ram machine, but at the moment have a 32 bit OS installed. In the system monitor, the RAM usage never exceeds 4.5 GB .. is it because of 32 bit OS ?